# How to retrive all the user account info and email and make a data view webpart

Tags: user-profile, active-directory

I am trying to create a data view webpart with url parameter ID (`_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=(@ID)`.. where all the user information especially user name, email and some basic information can be obtain in webpart, so in case the webpart can be used to pull the information instead of active directory.
For example, creating a email to user will be much easier if we get email address from webpart instead of active directory. `malito:{[..../domain/site/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=(Current()/@UserID)]/@Email address}`... 
Is there any way I can do this....

Comment: If you are in 2010 then why not use the standard User Profile page?

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand that the User Profiles are separate from the User Information List.  The User Profile is part of a centralized service and information store that will support one or more web applications, and numerous site collections.  This is typically set to sync with Active Directory or other sources on a regular basis.  The User Information List is managed at the site collection level.  With SharePoint Foundation it is populated at the time the user is first identified, but with Server it will periodically sync back with the user profile store.  Some basic properties like email, accountname and display name will be there, but not much else.  Your best bet if you have Server is to use the full user profile page or to access the full user profiles.